# What's the difference between "realpath" and "readlink -f"

Tags: filenames, command, readlink

I've read a lot about the `realpath` command and how it has been deprecated with `readlink -f` being now recommended. 
I have also seen in some places that the reason why realpath was introduced
was for the lack of such functionality in readlink
and that once it was introduced,
realpath was no longer needed and its support discontinued by most OS vendors.

The reason for my question is that I've also seen many people recommending `readlink -f` as a command "pretty much similar" to `realpath`, and that is what is bothering me, because no one elaborates on that "pretty much similar" part. 
What are the actual differences?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There are several `realpath` commands around.

The `realpath` utility is a wrapper around the [`realpath`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html) library functions and has been reinvented many [times](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=52483#10).

Debian used to maintain a [`realpath`](http://packages.debian.org/realpath) package ([separated](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=52483) from [`dwww`](http://packages.debian.org/dwww) since [woody](http://archive.debian.net/woody/realpath)) which hasn't changed except regarding packaging and documentation since 2001, but has now been phased out. This utility was deprecated because there are now more standard alternatives (GNU `readlink` and soon GNU `realpath`), but at the time, GNU utilities didn't even have `readlink` at all. This implementation of `realpath` supports a few [`options`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=realpath&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en) to prevent symbolic link resolution or produce null-terminated output.
[BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) also includes its own [`realpath`](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#realpath) command (which takes no option).

[GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) introduced a [`realpath`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html#realpath-invocation) command in [version 8.15](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7076) in January 2012. This is a compatible replacement for BusyBox's and Debian's `realpath`, and also has many options in common with GNU [`readlink`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html#readlink-invocation).

`realpath` has the same effect as `readlink -f` with GNU `readlink`. What distinguishes the two commands (or rather the various `realpath` commands from `readlink -f`) is the extra options that they support.

GNU `realpath` is not deprecated; it has the opposite problem: it's too new to be available everywhere. Debian used to [omit GNU `realpath`](http://bugs.debian.org/693211) from its [`coreutils`](http://packages.debian.org/coreutils) package and stick with its own `realpath`. I don't know why, since GNU `realpath` should be a drop-in replacement. As of Debian jessie and Ubuntu 16.04, however, GNU `realpath` is used.

On Linux systems, at the moment, your best bet to canonicalize a path that may contain symbolic links is `readlink -f`.

BSD systems have a [`readlink`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&sektion=1) command, with different capabilities from GNU `readlink`. In particular, BSD `readlink` does not have an option to canonicalize paths, it only traverses the symlink passed to it.

`readlink`, incidentally, had the same problem — it was also [invented many times](http://marc.info/?l=debian-devel&m=95154815527955&w=2) (not adding this utility when symbolic links were added to Unix was a regrettable omission). It has now stabilized in several implementations with many incompatible flags (in particular BSD vs. GNU).

Comment: `readlink -f` was in OpenBSD long before GNU. All of NetBSD, FreeBSD and OpenBSD now have `readlink -f` (your [link](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=readlink&sektion=1) even mentions it). `realpath` has been in FreeBSD and IRIX for a long time (don't know if it predates the one in Debian). HPUX and IRIX also have `readlink`, though not `-f`. The `realpath` package in Debian experimental is now the one from coreutils (as an experiment to see if it breaks things). The dwww `realpath` acts more like `readlink -e` while the GNU one like `readlink -f` so it's not a complete dropin replace

Comment: `realpath` has been in FreeBSD since 2002. Before that, `pwd` was doing it (since 2000, `pwd some-file` would call `realpath()` on `file`). Debian has had a `realpath` package since 1996. The one on IRIX probably predates it though I found no evidence other than it was in IRIX 6.5 in 1998. OpenBSD added a `-f` to `readlink` [in 1997](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/readlink/readlink.c?rev=1.10). [GNU added `readlink` in 2003](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2003-02/msg00008.html) and it had `-f` from the start.

Comment: Excellent summary thanks. Note a better bug for the request for debian to switch to the GNU variant is http://bugs.debian.org/730779 Even the existing realpath maintainer wants the switch to happen

Comment: Awesome answer. Missed only references to RHEL implementation of `realpath`. Does anyone know if it is somehow different from the `readlink -f` version?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh wow, lots of errors in my answers indeed. Thanks for pointing them out. Could you post a correct answer, and I'll delete mine? (Otherwise, I'll correct the errors, but it's more work to tack on to my long todo list…)

Answer (score 34):

**tl;dr** `readlink -f` will return `0` for a non-existent file in an existing directory whereas `realpath` returns `1`.  However, `readlink -e` will behave like `realpath` and return `1` for a non-existent file (see *Editors Notes* at end).

#### `readlink -f`

```
$ readlink -f non-existent-file
/home/user/non-existent-file
$ echo $?
0
```

#### `readlink -e`

```
$ readlink -e non-existent-file
$ echo $?
1
```

#### `realpath`

```
$ realpath non-existent-file
non-existent-file: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

#### `readlink -f` with non-existent directory

`readlink -f` behavior varies depending upon which part of the path does not exist.

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/non-existent-dir/foo
$ echo $?
1
```

#### `realpath` with non-existent directory

```
$ realpath /tmp/non-existent-dir/foo
$ echo $?
1
```

#### Availablity

`readlink` is already installed within most Linux distributions. Whereas, `realpath` is also becoming more often already installed as [`realpath` has been rolled into *GNU Coreutils*](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/realpath.1.en.html) (in prior years, it was it's own separate package).

### In summary

If you want to replace calls to `realpath ...` then use `readlink -e ...`.
However, `realpath` is becoming more widely distributed, so it's not unreasonable to expect `realpath` to be installed.

***MMV*** `readlink` implementations vary widely.
***MMV*** `realpath` availability in a default Linux installation varies somewhat more than `readlink`.

Tested with [*readlink (GNU coreutils) 8.21*](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils//manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html) and *realpath version 1.19* on Ubuntu 16.

---

#### Editors Notes

- **Ed.:** @AnthonyGeoghegan wrote "*this refers to the [Debian version of `realpath`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/realpath.1.en.html). The [GNU version of `realpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/realpath.html) behaves the same as `readlink -f`*")
- **Ed.:** @FilBot3 wrote "*this doesn't work on [MacOS High Sierra](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/readlink.2.html)*"

Comment: I upvoted this answer but I'd suggest clarifying that this refers to the Debian version of `realpath`. The GNU version of `realpath` behaves the same as `readlink -f`.

Comment: Can confirm that this doesn't work on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: Just in case, some versions of `readlink` may not output the path of non-existing entity with any of paths missing in the middle even with `-f` option stated (e.g. `GNU coreutils 8.32`) and will return code `1`. Busybox versions also differ and very.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other responses, the functionality of `readlink -f` or `readlink -e` (depending on the distribution) can be equivalent to that of `realpath`.  However, `realpath` the utility is not equivalent to `readlink`.  E.g., `readlink` can read/retrieve the contents of (the literal text in) a symbolic link file:

```
> ln -s "I am cold" slfile
> readlink slfile
I am cold
```

which `realpath` cannot do.

A symbolic link file, after all, is a text file interpreted as a "recipe" to move about the directory/file hierarchy.  But it is still a text file.  For example, its contents (what `readlink` returns) should be possible to be manipulated with `sed -i '...' slfile` -- in fact, option `--follow-symlinks` is to force `sed -i` to follow symlinks.  I write "should" because in my current setup (OpenSuSe 15.3 default, GNU sed 4.4, GNU bash version 4.4.23(1)) this malfunctions: `sed -i` without the `--follow-symlinks` option still wants to follow as a path the contents of a symlink file.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, concerning your statement _'A symbolic link file, after all, is a text file interpreted as a "recipe" to move about the directory/file hierarchy'_: This used to be the case in old Kernel implementations, but nowadays things are [a little more complex (see "fast symlinks")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609474/377345).